# what will be the regex that allow only one special character in a string. e.g if a user enter a special character twice (@@) then it will show invalid

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fahad 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your string");
      String s = input.next();
      if (s.matches("\\w{2,}\\.{0,1}\\w{2,}@\\D+\\.com"))
         System.out.println("Valid: ");
      else
         System.out.println("Invalid: ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question about your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two possible approaches.  The easier one is to use negative lookahead:

```
if (s.matches("(?!.*@@.*$).*")) {
    System.out.println("Valid: ");
}
```

The lookahead assertion matches zero characters, but it matches successfully only if the pattern inside is not matched by whatever part of the input has not been matched by any previous part of the pattern (of which there is none in this case).

It's more instructive (and more widely applicable) to approach it constructively, however:

```
if (s.matches("[^@]*(@[^@]+)*@?")) {
    System.out.println("Valid: ");
}
```

That matches an initial substring of non-`@` characters, followed by zero or more appearances of exactly one `@` followed by one or more non-`@` characters, optionally ending with one `@`.  It will match any string -- including an empty one -- that does not contain two adjacent `@` characters.